# Шансы и варианты

Tags: c++, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Есть несколько функций, и меняющиеся шансы для их вызова:

```
void a() { }
void b() { }
void c() { }

float aChance = 0.3f;
float bChance = 0.1f;
float cChance = 0.6f;
```

Я понимаю, что нужно сгенерировать шанс (0.0f - 1.0f) и сравнить с aChance, bChance и cChance. Но тогда, если шансы двух переменных одинаковы, вызываться будет та функция, которая первой стоит в if-else if-else.

Какой здесь нужен алгоритм? Спасибо!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Задача может решаться с помощью стандартного шаблона распределения [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution):

```
std::discrete_distribution<> dist({ список вероятностей });
std::cout << dist(генератор);
```

Пример использования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<> dist({ 0.3, 0.1, 0.6 });  

    std::map<int, int> m;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n)
        ++m[dist(gen)];

    for (auto p : m)
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
}
```

> 0 generated 2980 times
>   1 generated 1002 times
>   2 generated 6018 times

[Ссылка](https://repl.it/ErfX/4) на рабочий пример.

Comment: `2980 1002 6018`, а у меня `299648 100144 600208` - интересно, что направление отклонений совпадает - первое чуть меньше, а два других чуть больше. Наши генераторы как-то связаны? Или в чём причина? Или это вообще случайность?

Comment: @Qwertiy это совпадение )

Answer (score 4):

Как - какой? Сгенерировали?
От 0 до 0.3?     `a()`
От 0.3 до 0.4?   `b()`
От 0.4 до 1?     `c()`
Больше 1? Фигню сгенерировали :)

```
double p = rand()/double(RAND_MAX+1);
if (p < aChance) a();
else if (p < aChance+bChance) b();
else if (p < aChance+bChance+cChance) c();
else error("Так не бывает");
```

Comment: Для 10 вариантов уже станет так себе...

Comment: И насчёт error не уверен - может быть погрешность сложения. Тем более, тут строго меньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy Для 10 вариантов можно действовать по-другому. Насчет error - ну хорошо, подправил :)

Comment: `RAND_MAX+1`? o_O Что-то это ещё страннее выглядит... Почему бы просто последнюю ветвь (c) не отправить в else?

Comment: @Qwertiy А, что мы тут ни напишем - все равно [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/604240/195342) [@Vladimir Gamalian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185124/vladimir-gamalian) - вот идеально корректное решение на C++...

Comment: Да, уже плюсанул его. Впрочем, оно вызов функций не показывает - там только счётчик результатов инкрементится. Его надо с моим массивом функций скрестить :)

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/kOvj7F

Обращаю внимание, что последний элемент массива `1`, а не сумма. Это нужно, чтобы избежать погрешности при сложении. А ещё можно всё поумножать, чтобы работать с целыми.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int aCount = 0, bCount = 0, cCount = 0;

void a() { ++aCount; }
void b() { ++bCount; }
void c() { ++cCount; }

float aChance = 0.3f;
float bChance = 0.1f;
float cChance = 0.6f;

const size_t n = 3;
float chance[n] = {aChance, aChance + bChance, 1};
void (*f[n])() = {a, b, c};

int main()
{
    for (unsigned t=0; t<1000000; ++t)
    {
        float x = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

        for (unsigned q=0; q<n; ++q)
            if(x <= chance[q])
            {
                f[q]();
                break;
            }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n%d", aCount, bCount, cCount, aCount+bCount+cCount);

    return 0;
}
```

```
299648 100144 600208
1000000
```